# SQL between date range on string date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database and it has date_col in varchar form. I have read only access to database, so cannot modify the structure of the database. I am trying to find out all entries of table within June and Dec 2020.

I have tried the following query, but it doesn't work.

```
 SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_col, 101) as DATE_col_date
 FROM DW.table_name 
 where DATE_col_date between '2020-01-06' and '2020-31-12'
```

table_name (Date_col datatype is varchar)

```
Name   ID   DATE_col       Place
A       1     01/12/2020    P1
B       2     01/06/2020    P1   
C       3     01/01/2020    P1
D       4     01/04/2020    P1
E       5     01/11/2020    P1
F       6     01/08/2020    P1
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name   ID   DATE_col_date  Place
A       1     01/12/2020    P1
B       2     01/06/2020    P1   
E       5     01/11/2020    P1
F       6     01/08/2020    P1
```

**Error**

> Invalid column name 'DATE_col_date '.

Comment: Try this:

`SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_col, 101) as DATE_col_date FROM DW.table_name where CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_col, 101) between '2020-01-06' and '2020-31-12'`. Consider, this is very bad design to use string as a date. Use proper data type!

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string when it is already a string? Convert it to a date. And beware that you understand how `between` works. Its not always intuitive. The error is because you can't access an alias in the where clause but you don't need to.

Comment: @DaleK, i understand that `DATE_col` is string, but i can be wrong.

Comment: ^^^ You are correct - thats what OP says :)

Comment: @noob `I have a database and it has date_col in varchar form` that's a major bug that needs to be fixed ASAP. Dates are binary values, not strings. There's no `date in varchar form`, that's a varchar that can easily contain `potato` and can't be used with any date-related function, or even parsed without explicitly specifying a locale.

Comment: @noob the second bug is that the column name is `Date_col` not `Date_col_date`. The error is clear about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* long term solution here would be to make your `DATE_col` a bona fide date/timestamp type column.  That being said, if you must cope with your current design, then consider the answer below.

You should be calling `CONVERT` in the `WHERE` clause, when comparing your text date column against date literals.  Also, use `YYYYMMDD` date literal format to be unambiguous as to what you mean:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM DW.table_name 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DATE_col, 101) >= '20200106' AND
      CONVERT(DATE, DATE_col, 101) <  '20210101';
```

Note that if you are using a recent version of SQL Server, you could also use `TRY_CONVERT` here:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATE_col)
```

Also, I phrased the logic in the `WHERE` clause to include all dates starting with 6th January, 2020, until the end of 2020.  This seems to be what you want here.

Comment: Well... Don't you think that OP's database design is very poor? He should use proper data type.

Comment: @MaciejLos Tim answered that in the very first sentence

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, at this moment - yes. Earlier - not. :)

Comment: Now, the answer is correct and complete. Cheers! Maciej

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(DATE, DATE_col, 101) as DATE_col_date
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CAST(DATE_col AS DATE) between CAST('2020-01-06' AS DATE) and CAST('2020-12-31'AS DATE)
```

Try this it will work.