# Sql convert function is not converting the date

Tags: mysql

```
select * from transactions where CONVERT(DATE, vdate, 103) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31';
```

this is my query and below is the error I am getting for this query

[image]

below is the structure of the table

[image]

i tried Cast as well but that doesn't seem to work

EDIT 1:

1. I cannot convert the vdate in date type as I have to import old data from previous software that has more that 100k rows and date format doesnot work with that.
2. I got 103 from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp
3. I got the convert syntax from [SQL between date range on string date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841023/sql-between-date-range-on-string-date)

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from? I don't see any "signature" for CONVERT listed here, that would actually match what you wrote - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: And what is that arbitrary `103` in there even supposed to mean? Are you perhaps not trying to _convert_ anything, but perform a date operation such like adding 103 days?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: _"below is the structure of the table"_ - if `vdate` is supposed to represent a date value, then why is the column type VARCHAR? That is quite wrong, go and fix that first of all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the help center, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: 1- i cannot fix that as I have to keep that old data in this data from the previous software, and date format doesnot work with that

Comment: 2 - i got the 103 from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: 3 - i got the convert syntax from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841023/sql-between-date-range-on-string-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is using the `CONVERT()` function which is for SQL Server, but your question is tagged for MySQL.  The MySQL function to convert from text to date is `STR_TO_DATE()`.  If so, then you should be using this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31';
```

This assumes that your text dates be in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, which corresponds to SQL Server format mask 103.